# HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl

Tags: mariadb, database-connection, azure-aks

Using azure db server but getting this error continuously in spring boot application running in a pod in Azure Kuberenetes Service. Not able to solve it.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

It is happen long time inactive of database server. Restart the DB server.